# Javascript change cursor icon to local icon.jpg

Tags: javascript, dom, cursor

I am trying to change my cursor icon in a paint appliation using Javascript.
The jpeg icon which I want to use for that purpose is saved locally.
Can I use the following line to make this work?

```
document.body.style.cursor = "server/icon.jpg";
```

How could I make it work using a url alternatively?

Comment: I don't think you can load an image in JS directly from the local file system, without being served. This is for security, browsers don't allow JS to access the local file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `url` property instead:

```
document.body.style.cursor = "url('server/icon.jpg'), auto"
```

You may want to check MDN for documentation related with [cursor css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).